# How to solve calculations about  logical address space and physical address space?

Tags: operating-system

How to calculate number of bits in logical address  and physical address  when 
 logical address space of 8 pages of 1024 word each, mapped to physical memory of 32 frames?

Comment: How big is a word?  How big is a frame?

Comment: i find this question on internet and those details are  not consider in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the internet, i could find the solution for the question.

Each page/frame holds 1K; we will need 10 bits to uniquely
address each of those 1024 addresses. Physical memory has 32 frames and
we need 32 (2^5)
bits to address each frames, requiring in total 5+10=15 bits.
A logical address space of 8 pages requires 3 bits to address each page
uniquely, requiring 13 bits in total.

[this tutorial](http://garryowen.csisdmz.ul.ie/~cs4023/resources/sol11.pdf) will provide more details regarding this question

Comment: are you sure link to the tutorial is correct?

Answer (score 10):

15 is the correct answer

i think this is correct way
size of logical address space is No. of pages * Page size = 8 * 1024 = 2^3 * 2 ^10 = 2^13 No. of bits for logical address is 13

Size of Physical address space is 2^5 * 2^10 = 2^15 No. of bits for physical address is 15

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following room/floor analogy:  Each floor in a hotel contains 10 rooms. The door in each room is labeled 01, 02, 03, ..., 10. Then you get off the elevator, there is a plaque with the floor number.  There are 3 floors in this hotel: floors 1, 2, and 3.  Therefore, you can say that, to eliminate the ambiguity in room numbers, you concatenate the floor number to the room in the following format: floor:room.  So, 1:01 is different than 2:01, or 3:01.

### Viewing this graphically:

### 1 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 10 |

### 2 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 10 |

### 3 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 10 |

The floor number can be expressed with one digit.  The room number can be expressed with two digits.  To express the unique location of the room (floor:room concatenation), you need three digits.  Replace floor with frame, and room with page.

Answer (score 6):

There are 8 pages in logical address space so, `2^3 = 8` then page size of 3-bits
We have 1024 words(1 word = 2-bytes) then, `1024 * 2 = 2048 bytes`
which we can say that `2^11 = 2048` then so there are `11 + 3 = 14-bits` are the total number of bits in a logical address.
Now coming towards the Physical address:
we have 32 frames so `2^5 = 32` we have `5-bits for frame + 11 bits = 16-bits`
then we have 16-bits for our physical address.

Answer (score 5):

Offset for both pages and frames is the same to comply with design. In the problem, offset is 1024, so offset for page = offset for frame = 2^10.

Total bits needed to give logical address to each word of each page = 3+10.

Since there are 5 bits needed to uniquely define each frame,the Physical address will require 5+10 = 15 bits.

Answer (score 3):

size of logical address space is No. of pages * Page size
                                = 8 * 1024
                                = 2^3 * 2 ^10 = 2^13
No. of bits for logical address is 13

Size of Physical address space is 2^5 * 2^10
                                   = 2^15
No. of bits for physical address is 15

Answer (score 3):

here i think the main memory information is not needed at all.

Given Total no of pages = 8 and page offset is 1024.

we know that `logical address spaces is = total no of bits required to represent total no of pages + bits required to map page offset`.

Hence total bits required = 3 (because total no of pages is 8 and to represent you need three bits) + 10 (page offset is 1024 so you need 10 bits) = **13 bits all total.**

Thanks.